Sheaves and Fibre Bundles
Given a smooth manifold $X$, there is a 1-1 correspondence between locally free sheaves of $O_X$-modules and vector bundles, up to isomorphism. Now I was wondering if a similar correspondence exists for (locally trivial) fibre bundles. Given a fibre bundle $p:M\to X$, we can consider the sheaf of local sections. This would give a sheaf as we can glue these sections. However, we don't get any algebraic structure in this sheaf. Are there still some necessary and sufficient conditions for a sheaf over $X$ to be associated to a fibre bundle?

For general fiber bundles, the best thing is probably the sheaf of rings you get by taking the pushforward of the sheaf of smooth functions on $M$.

I recall there is an algebraic characterization of fibre bundles in Nestruev: Smooth manifolds and observables, but I don't remember any details and don't have the book near me now. But it might be worth checking out.
